# Divisibility relation on nonnegative integers.

Tags: relations, equivalence-relations

> Definition: $a$ divides $b$ if $b = ak$ for some integer $k$.

The book says that it is reflexive. But what about $0/0$ ? I am missing any point ?

**Is it not a paradox since for standard division operation it is not defined?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The definition of divisibility states that $a|b$ if their exists a number $k$ such that $ka=b$. Let $b=0$ and let $a$ be any integer (positive or negetive). Then $a|0$ since their is some number $k$ (what $k$ will work) such that $ka=0$.

**EDIT to address the comment**
The division operation $(a,b)\mapsto\frac{a}{b}$ asks for a *unique* $k$ such that $a=kb$. But if $a=b=0$, then any $k$ will do.

Comment: but is not it a paradox to standard division operation

Comment: @hambali I see nothing in that statement about division.  Or that $k$ should be unique.

Comment: ok my poor head i was deadly confused thank u

Answer (score 3):

By that definition, $0 = a\cdot0$, therefore every number divides 0. I don't see any problem.